# Saben como pasar un objeto Image a byte[] en java?

Tags: java, imagen, byte

Tengo un objeto Image y quiero llevarlo a byte[].

```
Image image   a   byte[] imageByte;
```

Comment: Marcan como q no se entiende la pregunta. Es pasar un objeto image a otro objeto byte[]. Que no se entiende? Alguien no pueda saber la respuesta pero no entender la pregunta !!! Igual ahí la respondieron. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque se pensaría que realizar esa conversion debería poder ser algo simple y lógico, como llamar un método dentro de la clase Image pero dista mucho de la realidad.

La forma en que yo realizo ese proceso es convertir la imagen a 'BufferedImage' la cual con algunos pasos extras es posible escribirla dentro de un 'ByteArrayOutputStream' para obtener los bytes de la imagen.

```
    public static byte[] imageToBytes(Image image) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage bImage = imageToBufferedImage(image);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", bos);
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    public static BufferedImage imageToBufferedImage(Image image) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics bg = bi.getGraphics();
        bg.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        bg.dispose();
        return bi;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta